# Declarando funciones en variables

Tags: javascript

Estoy iniciando es JavaScript, solo tengo un par de semanas que inicie una cursada y me siento super perdida, ¿Pueden ayudarme a resolver el siguiente ejercicio por favor?
Sé que debe ser super sencillo pero me frustra estar trabada en estas cositas.

> ¡Vamos a crear una función y asignarla a una variable!

*Primero creamos una variable con el nombre  ejemplo y le asignamos como valor una función. La misma debe retornar un String que diga: "hola, soy una función expresada".*

Y esto fue lo que intenté:

```
var ejemplo = [expresada];

function expresada() {
   return  "hola, soy una función expresada";
}
```

y me da el siguiente error:

```
Errores:
Debe asignar una función a la variable "ejemplo"
La función no debe recibir parámetros
La función debe devolver el texto solicitado
```

¿Alguna luz de como hacerlo?

Gracias

Comment: `var ejemplo = function () { ... } ` esto es asignarle una función a una variable. La función es anónima, es decir, no tiene un nombre que la identifique. Puedes leer más sobre funciones en la [documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions). Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Tienes un error de sintaxis en `ejemplo`. Por ahora, no tienes que entender qué exactamente hace la variable, pero es un [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array), sirve para agrupar datos.

Simplemente quítale los corchetes a la variable

```
var ejemplo = expresada;
```

Por otro lado, a pesar de que no afecta en cómo se ejecuta el código, es recomendable definir las funciones o variables antes de referirte a ellas, esto es considerado una buena práctica

```
function expresada () {
    return "hola, soy una función expresada";
}

var ejemplo = expresada;
```

Answer (score 0):

Me parece que esto debe funcionar.

```
function expresada () {
    return "hola, soy una función expresada";
}

var ejemplo = expresada;
```

Primero debes declarar la funcion y solo despues puedes referirte a ella.
Y si utilizas `[]` estarás creando un `Array` con `expresada` como único elemento, en lugar de simplemente asignar esa función a una variable.

Answer (score 0):

hay muchas formas de declarar funciones

[declarar funciones](https://dev.to/victordeandres/funciones-en-javascript-7-formas-de-declarar-una-funcion-523a)

En tu caso ya te marcaron el error escribiste [expresada]?
En tu ejemplo se asigna una función a una variable
y el error ya te lo marcaron quería mostrarte la utilidad de lo anterior y la forma de ejecutarla

```js
const ejemplo = expresada;

function expresada () {
    return "hola, soy una función expresada";
}
console.log('ejemplo no se ejecuta--->',ejemplo)// [Function: expresada]
console.log('se ejecita asi ejemplo()-->',ejemplo())
// Muy util  podes enviarla como parametro

function expresate (ejemplo,nombre){
    
    console.log(ejemplo()+ '-->expresate:'+nombre)
    
}

expresate(ejemplo,'Ana');
```

Answer (score -2):

```js
let ejemplo = function() {
  return "hola, soy una funcion expresada"
}

console.log(ejemplo());
```

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).